# Cloudera manager not showing completed impala queries

Tags: cloudera, impala, cloudera-manager

We're using a pre-built cloudera running on Azure, and whilst it seems to work quite well out of the box, there is one oddity that we've not yet figured out.

If you login to the cloudera manager, and click on the Impala service, then the queries tab, it never shows any completed queries.  So it's hard to go and find the long running queries.

If you look whilst a query is actually running, you can see them in the list. So it seems to have some sort of very aggressive clearing down, but I can't find what parameter that might be.

Comment: Check this https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/CM-don-t-show-Impala-queries/td-p/27680

Comment: Ah, yes that helped - post it as an answer and i'll accept it and add my detailed solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correction of hwclock time will resolve this issue

Comment: Correct sort of - The link helped identify the issue.  The issue wasnt hwclock, it was timezone.  Details here: https://chrisjean.com/change-timezone-in-centos/ And to be precise the issue was on the data nodes, not the master node. Somehow our azure cluster had different timezone configured.